# Globally registered process is not registered

Tags: process, erlang

I'm using

```
spawn (node, module, function, Args) 
global:register_name(name, pid)
```

To register a process on a different node globally.

Here's the code

```
Pid = spawn(mi, loop, [X]),
io:format("Glavni PID: ~w~n", [Pid]),
register(glavni, Pid),

Pid1 = spawn (prvi@Molly, mi, loop_prvi, []),
io:format("Prvi PID: ~w~n", [Pid1]),
global:register_name (prvi, Pid1),
```

When I run the code, it doesn't throw any error but when I try whereis(process) I get undefined on a node that spawned it.

Here's what process' console says:

```
Pid = spawn(mi, loop, [X]),
io:format("Glavni PID: ~w~n", [Pid]),
register(glavni, Pid),

Pid1 = spawn (prvi@Molly, mi, loop_prvi, []),
io:format("Prvi PID: ~w~n", [Pid1]),
global:register_name (prvi, Pid1),
```

And when I try to whereis(process) from any node, either the master node or the node I created the process on, it says:

```
(prvi@Molly)2> whereis(prvi).
undefined
(prvi@Molly)3> whereis(prvi@Molly).
undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

To register on several nodes you have to:

- start several nodes
- ensure they use the same cookie
- connect them (for example in node A, execute `net_adm:ping(B)`)
- start a process on node B with `spawn(node,...)`
- register it with `global:register_name(name, Pid)`
- check the registration with `global:whereis_name(name)`

you miss at least the last point, but all of them are necessary.